# mounted hook doesn't work after reload page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

My data doesn't appear on screen after reload page, but I have it on my store. I noticed after reload page mounted hook doesn't work. What it can be? I'm using nuxt

Comment: You need to reload the store on page refresh. maybe save the data to localStorage and when the page refreshes, reload the data to the store.

Answer (score 3):

This can be because of many reasons. How does the data end up in the store? Is it static (already hardcoded into the store data) or is it fetched from an other source like an API?

Without your code, there is not much I can do to help out though - please share it and i'll take a look :)

In general, get familliar with the concepts below so you'll understand how Vue and Nuxt work together and handle data:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram (this is the Vue lifecycle)
- https://nuxtjs.org/guide#schema (this is how Nuxt works on top of that)
- https://dev.to/lilianaziolek/understanding-nuxt-vue-hooks-and-lifecycle-part-1-48lc (an article explaining a lot about these concepts)

Comment: After reload all actions are working. I'm using asyncData for load data in store, I get it, but hook isn't work

Comment: Can you show us your component code? It would make the task easier.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a plugin that calls an `action` in your store which can load the data from another source such as `ajax` or `localStorage` and load the data into your state. You will also need something to save your state at some point.

An example module; if you are not using a module move this to `Vuex.Store({...})`:

```js
const store1 = {
  state: { value1: '' },
  mutations: {
    setValue(state, value) {
      state.value1 = value
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async load({ commit }) {
      let data = await fetch('/getMyValue')
      let json = await data.json()
      commit('setValue', json.value)
    },
    // Call `store.dispatch('store1/save')` to save
    async save({ state }) {
      await fetch('/setMyValue', {
        method: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(state) // Data should contain: { value: 'my value' }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

You would then create the root of store like the following which uses the above module. This has a basic plugin. Once the store has finished loading each function in the plugins array is called. In our case we will use it to load/init the data in the store or modules.

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // Remove if you are not using modules
  modules: {
    store1, store2
  },
  plugins: [
    store => {
      // Use `store.dispatch('load')` if you are not using modules
      store.dispatch('store1/load')
      store.dispatch('store2/load')
    }
  ]
})
```